# Why are my points being flipped or mirrored when I convert from DMS to DD?

Tags: coordinate-system, scale, ruby

I have a collection of crash data that provides latitude and longitude in degrees, minutes, and seconds that I'm converting to decimal degrees using:

```ruby
(degrees + (minutes/60.0) + (seconds/3600.0))
```

This appears to do a proper conversion, however the points (wgs84?) appear to be mirrored.  I feel like there's probably a simple bit of additional Math required to "fix" this, but I haven't been able to accomplish it. Any idea how I might do the conversion?

Here's a crude image illustrating what's happening:

[image]

Here's another illustration showing the points in context.  I'm assuming the shift in alignment is likely a projection issue, but the "flipping" effect is something different.

[image]

The data is provided as a CSV file, so I'm doing the conversions in Ruby.  I've used QGIS 2.2.0-Valmiera to render the images.

Here is the raw input of degrees, minutes, seconds and the output after the conversion.

```
45.0, 31.0, 22.9483924 = 45.52304122011111
-122.0, 40.0, 4.0819802 = -121.33219944994444
```

Additionally, here's the entirety of the conversion process in Ruby:

```
def to_decimal(row, type)
  degrees = (type == :lat ? row[:latitude_degrees] : row[:longitude_degrees]).to_f
  minutes = (type == :lat ? row[:latitude_minutes] : row[:longitude_minutes]).to_f
  seconds = (type == :lat ? row[:latitude_seconds] : row[:longitude_seconds]).to_f


  flip = type == :lon ? -1 : 1
  flip * (degrees + (minutes/60.0) + (seconds/3600.0))
end
```

Here's how I'm importing the CSV to QGIS (you can see some sample data in the screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Is the Data in the Western Hemisphere? Does the input longitude value have a negative sign? if not, then you just need to prepent a negative sign before your output.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe it is in the Western Hemisphere (Portland, OR).  The longitude values are negative.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using to render these points, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo I've edited my post.  Let me know if there's additional info that would be helpful.

Comment: It sounds the coordinates that you are showing us are your output from Ruby, and that the pictures are from QGIS, but I think it would be useful for us to know the exact steps you are using in between.  Are you perhaps using PostGIS?

Comment: @Caged: For one point can you give the input in DMS & the output? I think that you are not applying the negative sign to the Minutes and second parts

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I've updated my post with the info you requested and included the little bit of ruby I'm using to do the conversion on the raw data.

Comment: @PolyGeo That would be correct.  I'm creating a CSV file from raw data using the relevant bit of Ruby I just posted above and importing that CSV into QGIS as delimited file using the WGS84 projection.

Comment: Either the data you have shown is old, or you are not using the code that you have shown.`-122.0, 40.0, 4.0819802` should be  `-122.66780055005556` and not  `-121.33219944994444` according to the code you have pasted.

Comment: @PolyGeo missed your last question. I've also imported the points into PostGIS as means to experiment, so that's why you see the different formats above.  In either case (importing CSV or using PostGIS in QGIS or TileMill), the points are flipped.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Are you sure?  If you pop this in an irb prompt or a JavaScript shell environment "-1 * ((-122.0 + (40.0/60.0) + (4.0819802/3600.0)))" you get 121.33219944994444

Comment: Its the load into PostgreSQL/PostGIS that I think is the most likely to be involved but that step is still black box in your question.  The precise steps used to display PostGIS in QGIS are similarly obscure.  I think you should revise your question so that it goes from original input sequentially through to final map output.  I suspect that in doing so you will spot where it has gone astray but if not then people here will not need to guess what you did in any steps left out.

Comment: @Caged: it should be: (-(122.0 + (40.0/60.0) + (4.0819802/3600.0)))" note that the negative sign is outside the bracket.

Comment: @PolyGeo I've removed the PostGIS-related bits because they weren't that relevant and seemed to be distracting from the central issue.  I've also added a screenshot clarifying how I'm importing the CSV data to QGIS.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe (-1 * n) achieves the same result as prefixing the negative sign. That's what I was using above, but the comment was broken into two lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the map that you have given, One can see that the points are coming close to the expected point, and are about 1 Degree Away.

Lokking at your data, I can see that your code is converting  `-122.0, 40.0, 4.0819802` to `-121.33219944994444` when it should be `-122.66780055005556`

This tells me that while you are flipping the sign of the Degree Component, it is not being Applied to the Decimal part.

I don't know much of ruby, but I have edited your function, and this should work:

```
def to_decimal(row, type)
  degrees = (type == :lat ? row[:latitude_degrees] : row[:longitude_degrees]).to_f
  minutes = (type == :lat ? row[:latitude_minutes] : row[:longitude_minutes]).to_f
  seconds = (type == :lat ? row[:latitude_seconds] : row[:longitude_seconds]).to_f


  flip = (degrees <0) ? -1 :1
  flip * (degrees.abs + (minutes/60.0) + (seconds/3600.0))
end
```

You will see that I have made two changes:

- Firstly, instead of setting the flip flag based on whether it is latitude or longitude, I'm setting it on the basis of the value of the Degree component. This way you are not hard coding the sign change, and this function will work for latitude as well as longitude anywhere on the world.
- The second Change is the Important one. I am first calculating the angle in Degree-Decimal, and then flipping it, if required. For this, I'm taking the absolute value of the  degree component of your angle.

After making these changes the updated function gives the expected results

Comment: Thanks for the info, Devdatta. I've updated my post to clarify a few things.  It doesn't appear to be hemisphere related.

Comment: @Caged: I have completely rewritten my answer with ruby code which shows how you can solve this.

Comment: Perfect, @DevdattaTengshe!  I thought it would be a simple bit of Math, but I couldn't figure out what I was missing. After making these changes, rerunning the processing script and importing into QGIS, everything looks great!  Thanks for sticking with this through all of my edits.

Comment: Glad to help you out.